# с++ directx api, оптимизированный захват экрана

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, экран

Здраствуйте, моя программа должна накладывать шейдеры на бэкргаунд, в этот бэкграунд входит рабочий экран компьютера, получается. Мне нужно получать снимок экрана, рендерить его как картинку в окне directx и уже на него накладывать эффект. Проблема и заключается в этом рендере. Никак не могу оптимизировать это все, если я получаю изображение в потоке рендера окна, то видеопоток сильно отстает, а если в отдельном потоке, то быстро происходит утечка памяти. Вообщем не имею понятия как это реализовать. Есть ли какие то адекватные примеры видео захвата экрана для directx ??

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/DXGIDesktopDuplication

Comment: @user7860670 а на directx 9 такое есть?

Comment: Нет. Directx 9 устарел уже более 10 лет назад. в 2022 писать на нем что-то новое не имеет смысла.